# How to avoid scroll after adding element into ListBox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

My collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<Data> listData;
```

ListBox source:

```
ListBoxData.ItemsSource = listData;
```

Later i add elements 20 times at **start of collection**:
ListBoxData.Insert(0, new Data());

After adding ListBox scrolls to first element of collection. How to disable scrolling after adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this one works for you? ListBox .SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: I start remember index before adding new elements and set as SelectedIndex. Thanks for help! :)